# Firehose IP getting removed from VPC Inbound List repeatedly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have been successfully using Firehose to deliver to Redshift Cluster by adding Firehouse TCP/IP to the VPC group of the Redshift cluster. This IP was added under VPC security group's INBOUND list of IP with Port 5439.

IP is given here:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/controlling-access.html#using-iam-rs-vpc

I find my delivery broken and the reason is that IP was removed from the Inbound list of IPs. This has happened more than 3 times now spread across 2 weeks.

What can I do to prevent this

Comment: This should not be happening.  Do you have AWS Config and AWS CloudTrail enabled?  Enable them if not, and you should be able to identify the cause of the change.

Comment: I have CloudTrail enabled now and it is sending logs to S3. I made a table of the logs and tried querying: 
SELECT * FROM "cloudtrail_logs" where eventname like '%RevokeSecurityGroupIngress%'

I believe I will have to wait for the next event of IP removal to see any result.

Comment: Yes, I suspect that is the case.  The logs aren't retroactive.

Comment: type=AssumedRole, principalid=AROAJVIV6WONJFWMR4R4Q:DragonSIL

username=null, sessioncontext={attributes={mfaauthenticated=false, creationdate=2017-12-22T23:07:06Z}, sessionissuer={type=Role, principalid=AROAJVIV6WONJFWMR4R4Q,

source ip address 72.21.217.143